# KQL - Limit amount of data based on a specific column

Tags: azure, data-visualization, visualization, azure-log-analytics, kql

I have a log analytics workspace to which I feed VM metrics to. I want to render a timechart based on the data there, however I've run into a few issues.

The first issue is that I have a lot of machines and a lot of records, meaning they overlap and it's not very useful, therefore, I want to keep it at 10, as in, the 10 VMs with the highest average % Used Memory.

That said, using `top` or `limit` will literally limit the amount of data displayed, as it'll just put 10 points over the chart instead of limiting the amount of VMs I want displayed. How can I limit the data shown by the number of VMs?

Here's my query:

```
Perf 
| where ObjectName == "Memory" and CounterName == "% Used Memory"
| summarize UsedMemory = avg(CounterValue), any(Computer) by bin(TimeGenerated,15m)
| limit 10
| render timechart
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just want to confirm, you want to just show the 10 highest value for each vm?

Comment: No, maybe I said it wrong, but I want to show the highest 10 average values per VM. For example, a VM in the past time had an average of 50% Used Memory and I want it to show the timeline of the past, lets say, 6 hours, much like the innate metrics of Azure Monitor if you just create a timechart and decide you want 10 VMs with the highest average CPU percentage.

Comment: God even that comment came out wrong. I want to get the 10 highest VMs that have the highest average value descending. I am so sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide sample input (in datatable format), and expected output for this input.

Comment: @Gonçalo, please see the answer below:).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [top operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topoperator) and [partition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator).

The sample query should look like below:

```
Perf 
| where ObjectName == "Memory" and CounterName == "% Used Memory"
| summarize UsedMemory = avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated,15m),Computer
| partition by Computer
(
    top 1 by UsedMemory desc //fetch the highest value for each vm
)
| top 10 by UsedMemory desc //select the top 10 vm with the UsedMemory by descending
```

Comment: Thanks for the query! It did work, however the timechart looks strange as it only displays one value and scaling out throws the query under the bus. I'm going to test some stuff I haven't tried yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to first calculate the list of the top 10 computers and then plot them, for example:

```
let Top10Computers = Perf 
| where ObjectName == "Memory" and CounterName == "% Used Memory"
| summarize max(CounterValue) by Computer
| top 10 by max_CounterValue
| project Computer;
Perf
| where Computer in (Top10Computers)
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Computer
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the query! This is more related to what we need. However, for some reason, the values returned are huge: 400,000,000,000, for example. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/E2rV7QO.png). Any idea why might that be?

Comment: if you are looking for memory, this might make sense (for example 400GB), just pick one value from the table and see if it makes sense.